# Comments Align - PHP formatter (visual studio code)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

When I try to format my php code with **phpfmt - PHP formatter** (visual studio code) from:

```
function test( $test ) {

   // Check for $test
   if ( $test ) {
       echo 'TOS';
   }
   else {
       echo 'TUS';
   }

}
```

It will become:

```
function test( $test ) {

// Check for $test
   if ( $test ) {
       echo 'TOS';
   }
   else {
       echo 'TUS';
   }

}
```

As you can see the comment // Check for $test is not aligned vertically with IF statement. How to fix this?

Thanks